# How can I reduce bloating while taking creatine?

Tags: creatine

From a recommendation I grabbed a tub of Jack3d which is basically lemonaid with a ton of caffeine, but it also contains creatine. After drinking just one dose with 8oz water, I am bloated the next day in my midsection.

I've taken creatine mono and creatine hydro individually before and didn't notice any bloating. I did try another mix last year (bascially kool-aid and creatine, no caffeine) and there was some bloating but I was able to get it down with diuretics.

Diuretics don't seem to be helping in this case. What's the deal? How can I reduce bloating while taking creatine?

Water in take is probably ~64oz avg on normal days.

Comment: I'm always surprised users manage to perfectly formulate their question **in the question body** but fail to use it as their title. Ah well: fixed!

Comment: @Ivo sorry, I had a question to go with the title but the question morphed and the title was neglected. I always try to make the title as specific as possible in relation to my question. #TitleFail ?

Comment: i can suggest good and cheap creatine mono. Dymatize Micronized creatine 1000 grams for $19.99 comsumer labs did a test on a bunch of creatine and dymatize was one of the best. 5 grams is a serving so there is basically a s@it load of creatine there.  you can find it on bodybuilding.com under the store tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that this may be coincidence and the bloating isn't related to the creatine. My reasoning:

- You are basing this observation on one data point, and have observed no such effect when taking creatine in the past. What else did you eat or drink that day? Have you tried Jack3d again and noticed a similar effect?
- The caffeine in the Jack3d [*is* a diuretic](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/caffeinated-drinks/AN01661), so even without taking extra diuretics you should be getting some of that effect with the mix itself. This could explain why taking an extra diuretic didn't seem to matter.
- Creatine shouldn't cause you to retain water in your midsection; the extra water should be evenly distributed in muscle tissue throughout your body.

Counterpoints that could support your theory about *Jack3d* causing the bloating:

- Many drink mixes like this contain a large amount of sodium; the extra sodium could cause you to retain water.
- Jack3d contains a [lot of ingredients](http://www.usplabsdirect.com/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=111) besides creatine and caffeine. These are other variables that could be having some effect on your body.

Comment: It could be the other ingredients. As I said, I tried another product similar to Jack3d and I saw some bloating but saw no bloating when taking creatine by itself with juice. I actually ate nothing while taking Jack3d as the caffeine makes my appetite disappear.